# How to find a item in a Array matches user input ? jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I am having a Array with `Text` and `Value` fields  with a array of dynamic length.

I load my array content via ajax call from my controller

```
self.arr=ko.observableArray();

success : function(data)
{
    self.arr(data); //data having my items 
}

var listArray = self.arr();
```

I need to query my listArray with a input of type string say `kate` . If `kate` is present under Text of any of the items in array i just need `true` else `false` .

Well it can be done by running foreachloop and making loop run till it finds the matched and then exiting . I am not a fan of loops especially i dont want to showcase my code with those in most cases . Is there direct functions we can apply on array to get this thing done . something like Linq to entities in c# .

Any help is appreciated

Comment: this is an array of objects?

Comment: You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on arrays.

Comment: @kinakuta yes it is and user32342534 let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) to do lookups based on a predicate function:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6en3bue1/1/)

```
var listArray = [{id: 1, name:'Joe'}, {id: 2, name:'Kate'}, {id: 3, name:'Kate'}, {id: 4, name:'Mary'}];

var arrayOfKates = $.grep(listArray, function(obj) {
   return obj.name === 'Kate';
});

console.debug(arrayOfKates); 
// [{id: 2, name:'Kate'}, {id: 3, name:'Kate'}]
```

You could bind on this array using a `computed` function. Something like so:

```
self.katesArr = ko.computed(function() {
   $.grep(self.arr(), function(obj) {
       return obj.name === 'Kate';
    });
});
```

Comment: As on top user32342534 mentioned `some` which is also a cool one i made it work to my requirement and will try `.grep` and let you know

Comment: As i used `user32342534` `some` which looks best fit to my code as he didn't post it as answer i will mark urs which looks compelling and working fine . thank you

Comment: If you can post the code where you use `some`, I can work it into my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Knockout has a number of utility functions for this kind of thing ...

arrayFirst might be useful for you ...

```
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.myObservableArray(), function(item) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), 'kate');
    }
```

This is a good article showing this (and other) utility functions available in Knockout.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: yes it does and i love to use them but i cant use them in my scenario where code is separated in 2 js files blah blah . nice info i love use filters amazing one :) . thank you